# How can i prevent the loading of index function with __construct in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

i am building admin area for my app with CodeIgniter, i created a base Admin Controller in the library named: MY_Admin_Base that extends the CI Controller. and there i checking in the DB if the admin has access to the method.

```
class MY_Admin_Base extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();


        //check if the admin has premission to the page
        $this->load->model('admin_permissions_model');
        $query = $this->admin_permissions_model->get_admin_permission(
            array(
            'admin_id'=>$this->session->userdata('admin_id'),
            'page_id'=>$pages_cat_id)
            );

            if(!$query)
                $this->view->load('admin/restricted_area');
    }
}
```

the main class extends that MY_Admin_Base, and has index method, something like that:

```
class Main extends MY_Admin_Base {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() 
    {       
        $this->view->load('admin/main');
    }
}
```

the problem is that the both the views are loaded if the admin does`nt have access...the restricted and the main view.

someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In the MY_Admin_Base class create a variable to store whether or not the user is an admin:

```
class MY_Admin_Base extends Controller {
    public $is_admin = true;
```

Then change

```
if(!$query)
    $this->view->load('admin/restricted_area');
```

to

```
if(!$query) {
    $this->view->load('admin/restricted_area');
    $this->is_admin = false;
}
```

then in your index function, change the code to.

```
function index()  {
    if(!$this->is_admin) return;

    $this->view->load('admin/main');
}
```

Comment: but i will need do the checking for every method?

Comment: Yes, you will need to check in every method. An alternative could just be to use the die(); function to terminate the code execution after you load the restricted_area view, although depending on your environment that may not necessarily be a good idea. Another alternative is to create an array in every controller containing the names of the "protected" methods, then just use in_array inside of the constructer to determine if the user is allowed to access that method, if not then call the die(); function or use some other safer method of shutting down the execution of the application.